# Java record constructor invisible through reflection

Tags: java, reflection, java-15

I'm playing with Java 15's new records feature, and how it interacts with reflection. I've run into some strange behaviour, where I can sometimes access a record's constructor via reflection, and sometimes not. For example, given the following Java file:

`Recording.java`:

```
public class Recording {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Constructors: " + MainRecord.class.getConstructors().length);
        System.out.println("Methods: " + MainRecord.class.getDeclaredMethods().length);
    }

    record MainRecord(int i, String s) {}
}
```

This behaves as follows:

```
❯ javac --enable-preview --release 15 Recording.java
Note: Recording.java uses preview language features.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:preview for details.
❯ java --enable-preview Recording
Constructors: 0
Methods: 5
```

In other words, the call to `getConstructors()` does not find any constructors (while the call to `getDeclaredMethods() does find methods). I don't understand why not, because the constructor does exist:

```
❯ javap Recording\$MainRecord
Compiled from "Recording.java"
final class Recording$MainRecord extends java.lang.Record {
  Recording$MainRecord(int, java.lang.String);
  public final java.lang.String toString();
  public final int hashCode();
  public final boolean equals(java.lang.Object);
  public int i();
  public java.lang.String s();
}
```

(Putting the record in a separate Java file gives the same results.)

However, if I do the same from JShell:

```
❯ jshell --enable-preview
|  Welcome to JShell -- Version 15
|  For an introduction type: /help intro

jshell> record JShellRecord(int i, String s) {}
|  created record JShellRecord

jshell> JShellRecord.class.getConstructors().length
$2 ==> 1
```

So, now it **does** find the constructor.

Here's the Java version I'm using:

```
❯ java -version
openjdk version "15" 2020-09-15
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (build 15+36)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK (build 15+36, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Compiling and running the same program from Java 14 does work:

```
❯ java -version
openjdk version "14.0.2" 2020-07-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (build 14.0.2+12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK (build 14.0.2+12, mixed mode, sharing)
❯ javac --enable-preview --release 14 Recording.java
Note: Recording.java uses preview language features.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:preview for details.
❯ java --enable-preview Recording
Constructors: 1
Methods: 5
```

I know that in Java 15, compared to Java 14, a number of restrictions have been put in place regarding reflection on records, but if I read the [JEP](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/384) correctly, those only apply to modification. Finding (and perhaps invoking) a constructor does not seem to apply.

Can anyone tell my what's going on here? What do I need to do to see a record's constructor in Java 15 through reflection?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`getConstructors()` returns `public` constructors only. Use `getDeclaredConstructors()` to get all constructors.

Your declaration `record MainRecord(int i, String s) {}` lacks the `public` modifier, so it creates a non-`public` class and also a non-`public` constructor. See [JLS15-preview, §8.10.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/preview/specs/records-jls.html#jls-8.10.4)

> The implicitly declared canonical constructor has the same access modifier as the record class *R*, unless the record class lacks an access modifier, in which case the canonical constructor has package access

This does indeed differ from the JDK 14 preview. The beginning of [the JDK 15 preview document](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/preview/specs/records-jls.html) says:

> The changes are the same as those in the first preview of Records in Java SE 14, except for the following:
>
> …
>
> - 8.10.4 Removed requirement that canonical constructor must be public. Any access modifier must provide at least as much access as the record class. If a canonical constructor is implicitly declared, then its access modifier is the same as the record class.

It seems, top level classes created in JShell are implicitly `public`.

```
> jdk-15\bin\jshell --enable-preview
|  Welcome to JShell -- Version 15
|  For an introduction type: /help intro

jshell> record JShellRecord(int i, String s) {}
|  created record JShellRecord

jshell> JShellRecord.class.getConstructors()[0]
$2 ==> public JShellRecord(int,java.lang.String)

jshell> java.lang.reflect.Modifier.isPublic(JShellRecord.class.getModifiers())
$3 ==> true

jshell>
```